# How to allow user input with '&' safely?

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

For the sake of XSS attack, my project has code below that strips unsafe characters:

```
userInput       
    .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
    .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
    .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
    .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
    .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
```

When a user post a link to my website, it's fine if there's no `&`, but if there is `&`, it's encoded.

For example:

```
http://foo.com/bar?a=b&c=d
```

will become

```
http://foo.com/bar?a=b&amp;c=d
```

making the link broken.

If I don't encode `&`, there's no problem. But is that going to cause security problem? If so what's the proper solution?

Comment: You need to encode when concatening into HTML, only.

Comment: Where is `userInput` coming from, and where is the result going to? Currently it looks like you want to do html escaping for an url, which cannot work.

Comment: @Bergi userInput is the original input from user without any modification. It's then saved into the database and displayed on my website.

Comment: @SLaks user's input will be displayed on my website, so I should need to get rid of the unsafe characters, don't I?

Comment: @Arch1tect: So you're escaping your database content on the server side before inserting it into an html string?

Comment: Why is there a "link" in the user input in the first place? If he puts an URI there, it'll report that same URI back, but I don't see how it is "broken".

Comment: @Bergi The user's input is modified by my .replace() method before it's displaying on my website, thus the & is encoded and the link user see is http://foo.com/bar?a=b&amp;c=d now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87306/discussion-between-arch1tect-and-bergi).

Comment: @Arch1tect: Isn't it embedded in HTML where `&amp;` is a HTML character entity, so that the user only sees `&`?

Comment: @Bergi You are right! I checked it again and the & is actually encoded as `&amp;amp;`  Looks like it's a different bug.

Comment: You only HTML-escape like this at the moment when you put the content into an HTML context. `<a href="http://foo.com/bar?a=b&amp;c=d">` is absolutely correct and refers to the URL `http://foo.com/bar?a=b&c=d` in all browsers. If you are outputting to some context other than HTML markup then you should not HTML-escape.

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURIComponent(userInput);`

Comment: No.  This will not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

I see `&amp;` is the same as `&`, thanks to @Bergi .
The bug is somewhere else, where it's encoded twice as `&amp;&amp;` and breaks the link.